# writing in /sys/bus/pci/... fails

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Attempt to run the following command with root privilege on kernel 2.6.35 results in error:

```
% echo 0000:00:03.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/foo/bind
-bash: echo: write error: No such device
```

**UPDATE**
The device does exist in /sys/bus/pci/devices/ the output of lspci is as follows:

```
% lspci -v -s 0000:00:03.0
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 10
    Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at d010 [size=8]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000
```

Comment: Isn't 2.6.35 rather old? Anyway, what does lspci say about that device?

Comment: @CL, please see my updated message.

Comment: Show the `foo` driver's `probe` and `id_table`.

Comment: @CL, please see my second update.

Comment: You should put your solution in the answers section and mark it accepted.

Comment: @SLawson, could you show me how to mark the question accepted an resolved?

Comment: Three steps: First, edit your question to remove remove your solution. In other words, return it to it's original state as just a question. Second, in the answer section below, describe what you did to actually solve the problem. Make the description of your solution clear enough that if someone else reads your question and says "that's my problem too!" they will be able to use your answer to resolve the issue, and click "Post Your Answer". Third, under the voting arrows on your answer, you will see the outline of a checkmark. Click it and it will turn green. You have now "accepted" an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I resolved the issue. It appears that the driver requires to *unbind* device at first.

It also appears that the shell processes redirection (echo .. > /sys/bus/..) with user permission, and 'sudo' handles only the command, i.e. 'echo' but not the whole command line that follows it, therefore it has to be executed this way:

```
% sudo sh -c "echo 0000:00:03.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/foo/unbind"
% sudo sh -c "echo 0000:00:03.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/foo_new/bind"
```